# help with equivalence relations in real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, equivalence-relations

Let S be a relation in $\mathbb{R}$ defined by:
xSy iff $x^2-y^2=3x-3y$.

a) Prove that S is equivalence relation.

b) Find [a]$_S$ (for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary).

c) Describe $\mathbb{R}$/S.

I need help in particular for b), but any suggestions for others is welcome.

S is an equivalence relation if S is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

S is reflexive for all x in $\mathbb{R}$: $x^2-x^2=0=3x-3x$.

S is symmetric for all x and y if xSy then $x^2-y^2=3x-3y$ then $-(y^2-x^2)=-(3y-3x)$, hence $y^2-x^2=3y-3x$, therefore ySx.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$; so, this is equivalent to
$$
(x-y)(x+y)=3(x-y),
$$
or
$$
(x-y)(x+y-3)=0.
$$
When $x=a$ , what values of $y$ satisfy this relation?

Comment: Not quite.  Also, you're using set builder notation there to represent a set with size 1, which is not wrong but is a bit odd.

You know that $(a-y)(a+y-3)=0$.  From this, it follows that there are two possible values of $y$: $y=a$, and $y=3-a$.